# Defining a Job Manager with a queue of "Task" function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on making a Job Manager that will have a thread pool of worker threads, and each of those worker threads will pull from the queue and execute the given jobs if there are any.

What I am struggling with is actually calling the function pointer that I have stored in a concurrent queue.

I have defined a `CpuJob` struct as follows:

```
class ITask {};  // An interface that should be inherited 
                 // from if you want your class to be "Jobified" 

typedef void ( ITask::*task_func )( void*, int ); // A job function 
                                                  // MUST take a void* and an int 

struct CpuJob
{
    task_func task_func_ptr;

    void* args = nullptr;

    int index = 0;
};
```

And here is my `AddJob` Function:

```
 void Jobs::JobManager::AddJob_Member( task_func aJob, void * aArgs, int aIndex )
 {
     CpuJob temp = {};
     temp.task_func_ptr = aJob;
     temp.args = aArgs;
     temp.index = aIndex;

     readyQueue.emplace_back( temp );    // This is a wrapper around std::queue to be concurrent and thread safe

     jobAvailableCondition.notify_one();

 }
```

And inside my worker thread, where I want to call the stored function pointer, is where I get my error:

```
 // Other stuff popping jobs off the queue
 if ( !readyQueue.empty() )
 {
     CpuJob CurJob;
     readyQueue.pop_front( CurJob );

     CurJob.task_func_ptr( CurJob.args, CurJob.index );  // This is giving me an error 

        // Notify other threads that a job has been taken and we should probably
        // check to make sure that there isn;t more
        jobAvailableCondition.notify_one();
    }
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

`Error (active) expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type`

I think that it has something to do with how I am referencing the function, but I have tried several ways of doing to no avail.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). I think it will make your assignment easier in the long run.

Comment: I had a previous version using `std::function`, but it is 64 bytes! I need something that is much less in size

Comment: That sound like premature optimization for me. Are you on a small memory-constrained system? An embedded system perhaps? If not then don't worry about it, instead concentrate on writing good working code that is easy to maintain. Think about optimizations *last* after you have everything working (including tests!)

Comment: As for your error, don't forget that `task_func_ptr` is a *pointer* that you need to dereference. ***And*** that you need an instance of `ITask` to call it on!

Comment: There are memory requirements as well the fact that I need to abstract this to work with an external API that uses this methodology as well.

Comment: @benja the overhead of a thread is miles larger than the overhead of std function.  Stop premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

`task_func` is a pointer to a member function (`typedef void (ITask::*task_func)( void*, int);`).
When you call it you have to specify on which object it operates, e.g. `(some_object.*my_task_func)(some_args, some_index);`.

My advice: Don't pass member functions around. There are several alternatives, such as `std::function`, `std::bind`, pointers to regular functions and class hierarchies with virtual functions.

This is explained in detail in the C++ FAQ, section [Pointers to Member Function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Comment: Or std::invoke for C++17. `std::bind` is not advised anymore.